# How to reduce universal language to language of all turing machines that deduce all palindromes?

Tags: turing-machines, reductions

Let $S$ be language $$\{\langle M\rangle \mid(\forall x \in \Sigma^*)[x \in L(M) \iff x^R \in L(M)]\}.$$

How can I show that $L_U \le_m S$ and $L_U \le_m \bar S$ where $L_U$ is universal language and $\le_m$ means it is m-reducible (or simply reducible)? Can it be done via Rice's theorem?

Comment: Rice's theorem seems irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Show $L_U \le_m S$

Let $v=\langle T, w\rangle$, where $T$ is a Turing machine and $w$ is an input string to $T$. Fix two different input symbols $a$ and $b$. Construct Turing machine $M_v$ that upon input $x$, check whether $x$ is $aww^Rb$.

- If it is, accept.
- Otherwise, check whether $x$ is $bww^Ra$.

  - If it is, simulate $T$ upon input $w$.
  - Otherwise, accept.

It is straightforward to check that $v\in L_U$ $\iff$ $\langle M_v\rangle\in S$. The construction from $v$ to $M_v$ is computable. Hence $L_U \le_m S$

##### Show $L_U \le_m \bar S$

Let $v=\langle T, w\rangle$, where $T$ is a Turing machine and $w$ is an input string to $T$. Fix two different input symbols $a$ and $b$. Construct Turing machine $M_v$ that upon input $x$, check whether $x$ is $aww^Rb$.

- If it is, loop forever.
- Otherwise, check whether $x$ is $bww^Ra$.

  - If it is, simulate $T$ upon input $w$.
  - Otherwise, accept.

It is straightforward to check that $v\in L_U$ $\iff$ $\langle M_v\rangle\in \bar S$. The construction from $v$ to $M_v$ is computable. Hence $L_U \le_m \bar S$

Comment: How can I solve $L_U ≤_m \bar S$? I cant figure it out. I cant just check wheter $x$ is not $aww^R b$

Comment: Please check my updated answer. The only difference in construction is replacing "accept" at one place with "loop forever".